# Sum dataframe column that contains different data types

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame (df) with 2 columns (id and rate) which looks like:

```
id           rate    
0          #NAME?
1          #NAME?
2          #NAME?
3          #NAME?
4          #NAME?
5          #NAME?
6          #NAME?
7          #NAME?
8          #NAME?
9             0.5
10         #NAME?
:           :
211        0.25
212        0.00
213      #NAME?
214        1.00
215      #NAME?
```

As you can see the `rate` column has more than one type and I am trying to sum the non #NAME? entries in the rate column.  I have tried:

```
df = pd.read_csv(full_path, header=0, usecols=[0,8], dayfirst=True,index_col=[0], names=['id', 'rate'])
                 print(df)
                 sumRate = sumRate + df['rate'].sum()
```

but I get returned the following exception:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

I am unsure how to sum the floating values only, and unfortunately the format of the data I'm pulling into the data-frame is out of my control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `error='coerce'` parameter for convert not numeric to `NaN` first and then sum:

```
print (pd.to_numeric(df['rate'], errors='coerce'))
0      NaN
1      NaN
2      NaN
3      NaN
4      NaN
5      NaN
6      NaN
7      NaN
8      NaN
9     0.50
10     NaN
11     NaN
12    0.25
13    0.00
14     NaN
15    1.00
16     NaN
Name: rate, dtype: float64

sumRate = pd.to_numeric(df['rate'], errors='coerce').sum()
print (sumRate)
1.75
```